# Not Getting StringRequest Response in VOLLEY

Tags: java, android, json, android-volley

I Had Put this Dependency
to use volley and get JSON data from that respected URl:-

```
**compile 'me.neavo:volley:2014.12.09'**
```

after putting this 
Not Getting StringRequest Response :-

if i use other URLS its works fine , but with this URL not giving me Response.

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import com.android.volley.Request;
import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;

public class VolleyTest extends Activity {
//MY URL where i had made Json data
    public static final String MainUrl = "http://mycricket.net23.net/abcd.php";

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);

        Log.d("method", "GETDATA");
        RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
       StringRequest request = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, MainUrl, new Response.Listener<String>() {
           @Override
           public void onResponse(String response) {
           // SHow LOG of JSON data     
           Log.d("ResponseVolley",response);
           }
       },new Response.ErrorListener() {
           @Override
           public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

           }
       });
       //.. Adding Request
        requestQueue.add(request);
        }
}
```

Comment: try to convert response to JsonObject and print.may be it will work

Comment: You haven't told us what error you get if you do at all? If it works with other links then we should have a look at your php file... Also, why don't you use Volley from google's repository? git clone https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/volley get this version, go to Android Studio>New>Import module and give the path to the downloaded folder. Then in app build.gradle add   compile project(':volley') to the dependencies

Comment: I m not getting response ,..thats it

Comment: everything works well if i put Other URL.

Answer (score 0):

You're creating a new `RequestQueue` in the method context, but it's possible that once the method returns, the request queue is being garbage collected.

Try making the `RequestQueue` object a member of your activity, and create it only if it's still null.

Comment: sorry i am not getting you. what i have to change ?

Comment: move this line: 'RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);' to be under the line where your declare MainUrl, i.e., making requestQueue a member of the activity, rather than a variable in the method.

Answer (score 0):

The response from your php is JSON. It starts with a { not with [ so it's a JSONObject rather than JSONArray so...

Just follow the Singleton pattern, create a class like that:

```
public class VolleySingleton {
private static VolleySingleton sInstance = null;
private RequestQueue mRequestQue;

private VolleySingleton(){
mRequestQue = Volley.newRequestQueue(MyApplication.getAppContext());
}

public static VolleySingleton getInstance() {
    if (sInstance == null) {
        sInstance = new VolleySingleton();
    }
    return sInstance;
}

public RequestQueue getRequestQueue() {
    return mRequestQue;
}

}
```

then in your Fragment/Activity create your download method where you just make the Volley request and add it to the queue:

```
public void downloadMethod(String urlService, Response.Listener<JSONObject> successListener, Response.ErrorListener errorListener) {
    //final List<Event> myEventsList = eventsList;
    RequestQueue requestQueue = VolleySingleton.getInstance().getRequestQueue(); // this is where we use the Singleton
    JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest
            (Request.Method.GET, urlService, null, successListener, errorListener);


    requestQueue.add(jsonObjectRequest);
    Log.d("VolleyDebug", "REQUEST QUE ADDED SUCCESSFULLY");


}
```

Now, create 2 response listeners, where you actually handle the response:

```
 private Response.Listener<JSONObject > createMyReqSuccessListener() {
    return new Response.Listener<JSONObject >() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
            //handle JSON here
        }
    };
}


private Response.ErrorListener createMyReqErrorListener() {
    return new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Toast.makeText(MyApplication.getAppContext(), "ERROR:" + error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    };
}
```

And now to use the method:

```
downloadMethod(yourURL, createMyReqSuccessListener(), createMyReqErrorListener());
```

**EDIT:**

I forgot to tell you about the MyApplication class, it's very useful when getting context all around your app, so you might as well create it too:

```
public class MyApplication extends Application {
private static Context context;
//private static MyApplication sInstance;

public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();

    MyApplication.context = getApplicationContext();
}

public static Context getAppContext() {
    return MyApplication.context;
}

 }
```

BUT, you also have to declare this in your manifest `<application>` tag `android:name=".MyApplication"`

Looks like this:

```
<application
    android:name=".MyApplication"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/app_ico"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
```

Comment: It's a bit different than your implementation but the Singleton Pattern is good practice and the response listeners that you create like that make code clearer and you avoid problems. I had the response handled like you do before but there were delays sometimes in getting the response. Using those separate response listeners I have no problems. Now if you are new to JSON, go read a bit on how to handle JSON although it's pretty easy

Comment: when i create new class for VolleySingleton ...

mRequestQue = Volley.newRequestQueue(MyApplication.getAppContext());

get error over here "MyApplication.getAppContext()"

Comment: sorry, forgot about this class, look at my answer, I added info

Answer (score 0):

Might be there is prob. with your URL.

please check another URL and try again.